# Getting the same ID when clicking on the row layout inside recycler view (Android)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using a recycler view to list price quotations from a server. In the recycler adapter I am trying to get the ID of the price record by clicking or tapping on the corresponding row. Inside onCreateViewHolder. When tapping on the Relative Layout that holds the row, I am always getting the same ID (Which is the first Id returned by the server) although I am getting all the rows correctly from the server. What causing this to happen. is it caching ? and how to resolve it.

This is my code

```
 @Override
public ListViewPriceListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup    viewGroup, int position) {
    View itemView =    LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_fragment,    viewGroup, false);

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.price_list_row,null);
    ListViewPriceListRowHolder holder = new ListViewPriceListRowHolder(v);
    holder.rellayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            priceID = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_row);
            String priceIDStr = priceID.getText().toString();
            //here I am getting the same price id every time I click on diiferent row
            Toast.makeText(mContext,priceIDStr,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
    });
   // return new ListViewRowHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}
```

My ViewHolder

```
package com.mdawaina.helper;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.mdawaina.swftcc.R;

public class ListViewPriceListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

public NetworkImageView thumbnail ;
public TextView priceID;
public TextView orderID;
public TextView SPName;
public TextView catID;
public TextView price;
public TextView orderDetailsSuply;
public TextView approve;
public RelativeLayout rellayout;

public ListViewPriceListRowHolder(View view){
    super(view);

    this.priceID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_id_row);
    this.orderID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_id_row);
    this.SPName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sp_name_row);
    this.catID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat_id_row);
    this.price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_row);
    this.orderID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_id_row);
    this.orderDetailsSuply =           (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_orderdetailsuplly_row);
    this.approve = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_approve_row);
    this.rellayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pl_rellayout);

    view.setClickable(true);
}
}
```

My row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:id="@+id/pl_rellayout"
android:background="#FFF"
>
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/networkImage"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The Title Goes Here"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"


    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:id="@+id/tv_sp_name_row"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:shadowDx="3.4"
    android:shadowDy="2.5"
   android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_price_row"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_price_row" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="14500000"
    android:id="@+id/tv_price_row"

    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/networkImage"

    android:layout_alignRight="@id/location_icon_row"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/location_icon_row"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="التفاصيل"
    android:id="@+id/tv_orderdetailsuplly_row"
    android:maxLines="10"

    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_price_row"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="قبول العرض"
    android:id="@+id/btnAcceptOffer"

    android:background="@color/lightBlue"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_orderdetailsuplly_row"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

    android:shadowRadius="@integer/google_play_services_version"

/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="URL"
    android:id="@+id/tv_cat_id_row"
    android:maxLines="0"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/networkImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="URL"
    android:id="@+id/tv_order_id_row"
    android:maxLines="0"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/networkImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="URL"
    android:id="@+id/tv_price_id_row"
    android:maxLines="0"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/networkImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="URL"
    android:id="@+id/tv_approve_row"
    android:maxLines="0"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/networkImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/location_icon_row"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_price_tag"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/networkImage"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/details_icon_row"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_order_long_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/location_icon_row"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post implementation of onBindViewHolder() as well. You should set the click listener in onBindViewHolder().

Comment: Yes I set it on onBindViewHolder() right now and worked for me :). Thanks  Sagar Trehan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public ListViewPriceListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup    viewGroup, int position) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.price_list_row,null);
    return v;
}



public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public NetworkImageView thumbnail ;
    public TextView priceID;
    public TextView orderID;
    public TextView SPName;
    public TextView catID;
    public TextView price;

    public TextView orderDetailsSuply;
    public TextView approve;
    public RelativeLayout rellayout;


    public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);
        priceID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_id_row);
        orderID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_id_row);
        SPName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sp_name_row);
        catID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat_id_row);
        price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_row);
        orderID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_id_row);
        orderDetailsSuply=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_orderdetailsuplly_row);
        approve = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_approve_row);
        rellayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pl_rellayout);
        rellayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                priceID = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_row);
                String priceIDStr = priceID.getText().toString();
                //here I am getting the same price id every time I click on diiferent row
                Toast.makeText(mContext,priceIDStr,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewGroup` is not defined within the constructor of the `MyViewHolder`